# C++ - Enumeration range? Bjarne Stroustrup book

Tags: c++, enums

I am reading C++ programing language - of Bjarne S.
On page 77, section 4.8 I find this:

"An enumerator can be initialized by a constantexpression
(§C.5) of integral type (§4.1.1). The
range of an enumeration holds all the enumeration’s enumerator values rounded up to the nearest
larger binary power minus 1 . The range goes down to 0 if the smallest enumerator is nonnegative
and to the nearest lesser negative binary power if the smallest enumerator is negative. This defines
the smallest bitfield
capable of holding the enumerator values. For example:

```
enum  e1 { d a r k , l i g h t }; // range 0:1

enum  e2 { a = 3 , b = 9 }; // range 0:15

enum  e3 { m i n = 10 , m a x = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 }; // range -1048576:1048575
```

I do not understand why enum3 has that range

> (1048576:1048575)?  - (- 2^20 : 2^20 - 1)

Comment: if you have an actual question you'll want to include it in your post.

Comment: Are you qouting it exactly? It seems to be wrong if so. Perhaps `min` is supposed to be `-10`?

Comment: you should mention what edition you are quoting. there are multiple editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's should be a typo in your edition.  In my edition (The C++ programming langage - special edition, 12th printing, May 2005) of the same book, I read

```
enum e3 { min = -10, max = 1000000 };
```

which is in line with the text.

**Additional explanation:**

Stroustrup explains that the range is based on *the smallest bitfield capable of holding the enumerator values*. With 20 bits you can represent 2^20=1048576 different values. As you start your count from 0 and not from 1, you can go to max 2^20-1.  This explains the highest range.

Now he explains that *the range goes down to 0 if the smallest enumerator is nonnegative*.  This means that if **min = 10**,  the range would be from **0** to 1048575.

He also explains that the min range shall be rounded *to the nearest lesser negative binary power if the smallest enumerator is negative* which applies for **min = -10**.  This sentence alone would be ambiguous : you could think that le smallest power of two below -10 would be -16.  But the sentence has to be connected with the fact that the range is defined by the ***smallest bitfield*** capable of holding the values.  Hence, you need 20 bits+ the sign bit, and according to the conventions you can represent with this the values from -2^20 to +2^20-1.

Comment: I have an old edition indeed. From 2000, but the question is witch is the range for that enum?

Comment: Sorry ! I thought you didn't understand because of the mismatch.  I'll clarify in an edit

Comment: @victor does the additional explanation answer clarify what you where looking for ?